# Merge two data.frames with replacement

Tags: r, join, merge, dataframe, data.table

I have two datasets. First one is smaller, but have more precise data. 
I need to join them, but:
1. If I have some data in Data1 - I'm using only this data.
2. If I haven't got data in Data1, but they're in Data2 - I'm using only data from Data2.

```
Data1 <- data.frame(
    X = c(1,4,7,10,13,16),
    Y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
)

Data2 <- data.frame(
    X = c(1:10),
    Y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
)
```

So my data.frame should look like that:

```
DataJoin <- data.frame(
    X = c(1,4,7,10,13,16,7,8,9,10),
    Y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
)
```

How can I do that? 
I've tried somehow option merge form base package and data.table package, but I couldn't make it happend, as I like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no join needed. You can reformulate the problem as "add the data found in Data2 and not found in Data1 to Data1". So simply do:

```
id <- Data2$Y %in% Data1$Y
DataJoin <- rbind(Data1,Data2[!id,])
```

Gives:

```
> DataJoin
    X Y
1   1 a
2   4 b
3   7 c
4  10 d
5  13 e
6  16 f
7   7 g
8   8 h
9   9 i
10 10 j
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`:

```
d1 <- data.table(Data1, key="Y")[, X := as.integer(X)]
d2 <- data.table(Data2, key="Y")

# copy d2 so that it doesn't get modified by reference
# i.X refers to the column X of DT in 'i' = d1's 'X'
ans <- copy(d2)[d1, X := i.X] 
     X Y
 1:  1 a
 2:  4 b
 3:  7 c
 4: 10 d
 5: 13 e
 6: 16 f
 7:  7 g
 8:  8 h
 9:  9 i
10: 10 j
```

Comment: Hi Arun, maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I'm using Your code - as a result I have only data from d2...

Comment: Yes, you mention in your post - *I'm only using data from Data2*. So, I thought you want only those that match the two to be replaced and leave the rest be.

Comment: I guess you're looking for something like: `d1[d2][is.na(X), X := X.1][, X.1 := NULL][]`

Answer (score 1):

```
DataJoin <- merge(Data1, Data2, by="Y", all=TRUE)

DataJoin$X.x[is.na(DataJoin$X.x)] <- DataJoin$X.y[is.na(DataJoin$X.x)]
DataJoin[,1:2]

#    Y X.x
# 1  a   1
# 2  b   4
# 3  c   7
# 4  d  10
# 5  e  13
# 6  f  16
# 7  g   7
# 8  h   8
# 9  i   9
# 10 j  10
```